# If $g(2)= 3$ and $g'(2)=-1$, what is the value of $\frac{d}{dx} (\frac{g(x)}{x^2})$ at $x=2$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I tried applying the quotient rule for the given problem.

$\frac{g'(x^2)-(2x)(g(x))}{(x^2)^2}$

$= \frac{(-1)(4)-(2(2))(3)}{(2)^4}$

$= \frac{-4-12}{16}$

$= \frac{-16}{16}$

$=-1$

I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: approach is correct and formatting the question better would have been nice.

Comment: thanks but sorry idk how to format on stack exchange

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You have used the quotient rule wrong. It should be $x^2(g'(x))$ and not $g'(x^2)$. That might just be a typo.(I have not evaluated for the correct answer yet.)

Comment: You could check yourself by creating a simple function for $g(x)$ that fits the conditions.  Say $g(x) = -x  + 5$.

Comment: @ShootingStars OP might be referring to $g'(x^2)$ as $(g')(x^2)$, or $(g'(x))(x^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The quotient rule was correctly used, although the notation was quite ambiguous. For example, since we have $g(x)$ as function, writing $g'(x^2)$ is a different thing compared to $(g')(x^2)$ or $(g'(x))(x^2)$. The former expression means that we differentiate $g$, and evaluate $g'$ at $x^2$. Other than that, the solution is good.